# Sublime 3 abbreviation expander

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm having an annoying problem on Sublime 3 while working on SASS files. After I type a colon `:` and then hit tab, it outputs another colon plus a semicolon `::;`. Also it changes my declarations with what seems to be recommendations or something. For instance if I type in `width:` and then hit the tab, it changes `width:` to `windows:`.

I've been researching around to see what could cause this. I added `"tab_completion": false` and `"auto_complete": false` to my User sublime settings but that didn't fix it. Then I found that it might be the Emmet package that is causing this so I added `"disable_tab_abbreviations_for_scopes": "source.scss, source.css"` to my Emmet User settings but that didn't fix it either. Each time I've made a settings change I've closed Sublime and restarted.

I know I can use `shift + tab`, but I really would like to find out what is causing this as I'm starting a big SASS project and this is getting really annoying. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is to add a keybinding to force ST to the desired behavior instead of changing the settings to entries you might not want.

Just add this to your keymap and a tab will be inserted in the described scenario:

```js
{
    "keys": ["tab"],
    "command": "insert",
    "args": {"characters": "\t"},
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.css, source.sass" },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": ":$" }
    ]
},
```